# Can we always draw a circle that is internally tangent to three circles?

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, euclidean-geometry, geometric-construction

Here is the picture of the problem:

[image]

I'm looking for an intuitive explanation and also an outline of how a rigorous proof would look like.
Our professor directly started to speak about finding the radius of the small circle, but it got me thinking. How can we ensure that such a circle always exists?

I researched and came across [Appolonius Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Problem_of_Apollonius#:%7E:text=Apollonius%20problem%20is%20to%20construct,circles%2C%20points%2C%20or%20lines.), but I couldn't find an explanation for my problem. I know that three points define a circle, but how does that help me?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Imagine placing a point somewhere between the three circles, then start to "inflate" it into a circle. When it touches the first of the original circles, keep it tangent to that circle and continue inflating it until it touches the second circle. Repeat until it touches the third. If a solution [exists](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Problem_of_Apollonius#Number_of_solutions) at all, you will have found one.

Comment: If you have an answer, post it as such, so it can be voted appropriately. Comments are suggesting improvement and seeking clarification, not for anything else. @dxiv

Comment: @Nij Comments are well suited for hints, and that was a hint at best. Which did not even begin to touch the other "*outline of a rigorous proof*" part of the question.

Comment: Comments are not suited for hints, this is clear from the definition of comments on Stack Exchange. Hints are more than acceptable as answers, as thousands of posts and millions worth of rep show.

Comment: See [Descartes' Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Descartes%27_theorem)

Comment: Not if the three circles
are concentric.

Comment: See here: https://www.cut-the-knot.org/pythagoras/Apollonius.shtml

Comment: @dxiv Thank you for the nice explanation. I just don't see how to continue inflating it when it is already in contact with two circles already. Wouldn't that require to move the circles?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

Hint: As can be seen in figure:

1- Connect centers A, B and C of three circles.

2-Find circumcenter D of ABC.

3-E is the center of big circle and F is that of small one. By accurate drawing we can see that D is midpoint of EF. The radius of big circle is:

$R=DA+\frac {AA'+BB'+CC'}3$

And that of small one is:

$r=DA-\frac {AA'+BB'+CC'}3$

4- for big circle take for example point A' and B' as centers of two circles which intersect at E, this is the center o big circle.

5- For small circle take for example two points, intersection of DA and DB with circles A and B, as centers of two circle with radius r which intersect at F , this will be the center of small circle.You may also connect D to E and extent it equal to DE from D to find F.

Comment: Good construction if all the circles are external to each other. You may want to add that qualification.